# System.Data.Linq the given assembly name or code base was invalid

Tags: web-services, linq

I have a webservice in my sharepoint site which uses System.Data.Linq to add some data to the database. If I make a call to this webservice, I get the following error:

> The given assembly name or codebase, 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.Linq\3.5.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.Linq.dll', was invalid.

How can I fix this error?

UPDATE: I've alreay added the assembly to the web.config:

```
<system.web> 
<compilation> 
  <assemblies> 
    <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" /> 
  </assemblies> 
</compilation>
```

Comment: Were you able to solve the problem, I am having the same issue . Please help

Comment: I think (but I am not sure) I ended up recreating the webapplication. It was in my development environment so it wasn't really a problem to do that.

Comment: Hem that Sounds That you have installed a newer Version of the .net Framework and Removed or damaged the .net version 3.5 (i do not Know how this can Happen..) can you try to Reitstall the .net Framework 3.5?

Comment: It's ok =) Please add this in your question and I will delete my unhelpfull answer. Are u try to use this assembly from another application? May be it's realy corrupt.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add entry to web.config of your application

```
  <system.web>
    <compilation>
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
  </system.web>
```

Comment: I already did that, sorry forgot to write that in my post :(

Comment: It's ok =) Please add this in your question and I will delete my unhelpfull answer. Are u try to use this assembly from another application? May be it's realy corrupt.

Comment: If I use it from another application everything works fine.